# Should I play Overcooked before Overcooked 2?

Tags: overcooked-2, overcooked

I'm looking for a cute co-op game to play with my wife and found Overcooked. If I can only play one, does it make more sense to go with Overcooked or Overcooked 2?

Comment: You might want to keep in mind that Overcooked co-op play ruined more than one relationship :)

Comment: @Philipp Haha, thank you. I'll make sure I pick the time carefully.

Comment: Never play Overcooked 1 (at least not on Xbox). It'll make your gamerscore uneven, unless you can 100% the game...

Comment: I played Overcooked with my then-girlfriend-now-ex (could be an omen) and it wasn't a good time for either of us, based on how differently we both approached games. So keep in mind that this game has the potential to cause very frustrating situations.

Comment: Everyone in my household found the first one frustrating after getting past the first handful of levels. Specifically what's frustrating is that you will run out of time over and over and not know what you need to do differently. I don't know if 2 is better in this regard. People who like these games seem to *really* like them, but they're not for everyone. There are better local multiplayer co-op games out there IMHO.

Comment: @mechmk1 thank you! How do you mean you approached them differently? Trying to win vs not?

Comment: @mentalist thanks a lot for warning me! Would you mind suggesting a couple local co-op games that you prefer? She's absolutely not a gamer.

Comment: @Anna "Tricky Towers" is cute you like Tetris-like games, "Lovers in a dangerous space-time" too. My favourite couch co-op game is Towerfall.

Comment: @Anna I was trying to play it very casually, while my ex was very "try hard", pushing for a 3 star rating on every level. That made it very unfun for me, as she constantly implied I wasn't good enough, I wasn't trying hard enough, etc.. I'm not saying that that is the game's fault, but the game can create situations in which one player can feel uncomfortable, which is something to be aware of.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It makes more sense to go with **Overcooked 2**. It's longer, has more levels, more content and more features.

Also because it has online co-op (Overcooked 1 only has local co-op). (I don't think this matters to you because you're probably going to play couch co-op with your wife, but I want to add it for the general answer).

Comment: Yes, only local co-op is relevant. Thank you for your answer! Are there any advantages at all with Overcooked 1? There's no story, right?

Comment: @Anna There's a story in Overcooked 1, yes. The only advantage is that it has different levels than Overcooked 2. So whenever you've finished all the content in Overcooked 2, if you still want more, you can go to Overcooked 1 and play its campaign.

Comment: +1 to all of this. Additionally, in Overcooked 2, you can throw raw food toward other players. Once I was introduced to that, I hated playing Overcooked 1 without it. Also, if it helps, my spouse and I consider Overcooked one of our favorite couch co-op games. We wish it had a level editor.

Answer (score 16):

If you can only purchase one title, get [Overcooked: All You Can Eat](https://www.team17.com/games/overcooked-all-you-can-eat/) instead of either of the original games. It’s a remastered compilation of **both** games, with an enormous amount of additional content.

Comment: Possible caveat for XBox One users:  I've only seen 'All you can eat' on XBox Series X

Comment: There are several reports that online coop with Overcooked: All You Can Eat is very unstable for many users. Looks like this doesn't apply to Overcooked 2 or at least not to this extent.

Answer (score 1):

If you plan on playing both, starting with Overcooked 1 will help appreciating  both. 2 is superior and 1 will most likely feel like a disappointment afterwards.